# Modifying routing table using .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, networking, routes

Is there any way to modify routing tables using the .NET framework? Or do I have to use P/Invoke with Windows API? In that case, which APIs would be most helpful? Can someone point me in the right direction here?

If you have a code example in C# I'd be most grateful!

Comment: You could certainly do it by calling a command line script via Process.Start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with P/Invoke. The best example I can find on this is [here](http://pastebin.com/mvLYvgbg).